# black and white vertical lines in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, 64-bit, display, desktop-environments

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit yesterday in my PC. But today, desktop turned into striped lines many times and I had nothing to do except pressing the power button on CPU. Don't know why this is happening, which application is causing this. I installed ubuntu using this ISO "**ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso**".

I am using Unity Desktop. Ubuntu is fresh and I just upgraded it today using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Here is the screenshot taken by mobile (Sorry for bad quality of picture):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Woi.jpg

**UPDATE:**

Another strange problem I am facing is that when I try to browse any site of google like www.google.com/chrome. Firefox gets crashed along with whole desktop, I also tried on Gnome Classic, it is also crashing. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: You might want to run the memtest option from the boot menu of the install cd.

Comment: I installed using ubuntu live usb

Comment: Same thing.. pick the memtest option from the boot menu.